# How to align several elements vertically within one another

Tags: html, css

How would I centre vertically the div#headerinner within the div#headerouter, and the img.header within the div#headerinner?

I have tried using vertical-align, but it doesn't have any effect.

I have been able to manually calculate the number of pixels and use padding, but is there a way to automatically align vertically that would work here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:red;

}

div#headerouter { 

    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    background-color:yellow; 

}

div#headerinner {

    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;

}

img.header {

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

span#login {

    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

div#menu {

    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;

}

div#menu ul {

    position:relative; 
    align:top;
    text-align: center; 
    height:40px; 
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:green;

}

div#menu li { 

display: inline;
padding-right: 50px;

} 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="headerouter">
<div id="headerinner">
<span id="login">Welcome!</span>
<img class="header" src="mysite/heading.png" alt="Header">
</div>
</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, there is. http://jsfiddle.net/cAR6T/1/ But really for your use case, I recommend that you just pre-calculate and use padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4AFH/1/)

use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` in your id selectors..

```
div#headerouter { 

    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    background-color:yellow; 
    display: table;
}

div#headerinner {

    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: updated fiddle..? there's no fiddle in question to update lol :D

Comment: Thanks. This works, however div#headerinner streches to 100% of the screen width instead of being just 900px wide. Is there a way to prevent this?